# How much time does it generally take to get Semicha?

Tags: torah-study, rabbis, yeshiva-school, semicha, college-university-school

What is the average amount of time that it takes to get Yoreh Yoreh Smicha?
Yadin Yadin?

And in Israel to pass each of the Rabannut tests? To get "Rav Shchuna"? "Rav Ir"?

I understand that it depends on the particular person, but I'd like to get a sense of the range.

Comment: Depends. Some programs are 2 years, some are 5 years, some are 4 years. But its not the time spent, it is the material covered ie. Issur Veheter, Nidda, shabbos...shimush as well

Comment: Some programs, notably habad and iirc aish, are less than 2 years. All depends on the program.

Comment: I’ve also seen three-year ones. This question also presupposes that all semichos are created equally - some are Yoreh Yoreh, some are Yadin Yadin, and some are both. Debating whether to flag as too broad.

Comment: It is indeed too broad. I know of people who got multiple semichas from different programs. Each program took a different period of time based on what they were studying, what previous semicha they had, as well as the level that they were intending to go to and what they were planning to do with it.

Comment: This is a broad / opinion type question. Even with a yeshiva that indicates a time-frame, much of it also depends on the student's ability and effort. Some students understand quickly and complete ahead of time. Others take longer. Still others begin and either drop out or are encouraged to leave by the Rosh Yeshiva. Semicha is not for everyone. I'm not even touching those who, perhaps, should not become rabbis at all, but the yeshiva keeps them in and gives them semicha, anyway.

Comment: @mevaqesh But in many cases a Chabad rabbi doesn't have the schooling to serve as a Rov.

Comment: @ezra indeed the popular Chabad "semicha" was never meant to be a rovs semicha. It's purpose was that everyone should have a working decent understanding of the laws of kashrus.